# Run other script node.js in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, npm-scripts

I have a node.js application that starts with npm start, but the same application also has another script that is npm queueProcessor that starts rabbitMQ queue listeners my wish is to run npm start in an ElasticBeanStalk instance and in another instance rotate the queueProcessor. But I have no idea how to do this

Comment: got any solution ?